# firestore -- Add element in a field in hashmap

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Above is the structure of collection "networks". What is want to do is add another element in "users" field. It's a `HashMap`. I want to achieve is Key= xyz@gmail.com and its values {displayName: "Anirudh Kumar", "role":"admin"}.

xyz@gmail.com
    displayName: "Anirudh Kumar"
    role: "admin"

I have tried few things but it doesn't seems to work.

1st option

```
        Map<String, Network.NetworkUser> users = new HashMap<>();
        users.put(email, networkUser);

       db.collection("networks").document("id")
          .update("users",FieldValue.arrayUnion(users));
```

2nd option

```
       db.collection("networks").document(userNetwork.getNetworkUid())
                                .set(users,SetOptions.merge());
```

3rd option

```
                            db.collection("networks").document(userNetwork.getNetworkUid())
                                .update("users."+email,networkUser);
```

[image]

3rd option takes me closer to answer, but because of dot [.] in an email it creates another row, let me know if somehow this can be avoided.

If anyone can assist me how can I achieve the desired goal, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to redact the email address shown in your post.

Comment: Its alright @TeymourAldridge..

Comment: @TeymourAldridge But the OP's email address is easy to guess given the username that he's using for StackOverflow.

Comment: I was just checking to make sure it hadn't been included accidentally, in error.

Comment: Thank you for your concern @TeymourAldridge.. Can you help me in figuring out the problem?

Comment: My java knowledge is pretty limited. I know in javascript there are some special methods for handling the adding and removing of elements from arrays – perhaps there is something similar in java for hashmaps?

Comment: @AnkitOstwal: try this way `db.collection("networks").document(userNetwork.getNetworkUid()).collection("users")
                                .document(<Email_id>).set(users);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i have tried this already, but it creates a new collection instead of adding value in a field "user" that already exists .

Comment: The first option should work, but you have to replace the document ID with the appropriate network ID.

Comment: @Edric It is not working. What is does is , it creates an index

0
xyz@gmail.com
   displayName: "Anirudh Kumar"
   role: "admin"

It adds index 0 here. 

I have just added dummy document id here as "id", i am using actual document id.

Comment: its a structure i am following in firestore. I can't change it. @PeterHaddad

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK , can you please check option 3 i have just uploaded.. If somehow i can achieve the target.

Comment: @Edric, can you please check option 3 i have just uploaded.. If somehow i can achieve the target.

Comment: perfect! tanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your attempts work because you are trying to update a document using a `Map` in which the value is an object of type `Network.NetworkUser` and this is not possible, because there is no way you can map that object to a `HashMap`.

What is `users` property? In fact, is a property of type `Map`, which contains in terms other HashMaps. So you need to get the document first, get the value of `users` property, cast to a `Map<String, Object>` and put inside another `HashMap`. This new HashMap contains an object with the email address as the key and another `HashMap` as a value, which again in terms contains two keys with two values. After you add the desired data to the Map, simply write the document back.

If you don't want that behavior, you can simply create a subcollection of users under each (Network.NetworkUser) document.

Comment: Hi Alex , i didn't got your point of, " get the value of users property, cast to a Map<String, Object> and put inside another HashMap". Do you mean i should get a reference to users property?

Comment: db.collection("networks").document(userNetwork.getNetworkUid()).get()

Do you mean something like this.?

My doubts may sound little silly, as i am new to Firestore, so i would appreciate it if you can help me get out of it.

Comment: Also if you look at option 3, i tried, because of dot [.] i could not get my issue resolved. Otherwise it was a workable solution.

Comment: Yes, you get the document first using `db.collection("networks").document(userNetwork.getNetworkUid()).get()`, attach a listener and get the value of the `users` property. SInce you cast that value to a `Map<String, Object>`, you can than add another HashMap with the structure that is explained in my answer.

Comment: Solution three won't work too since you are using a `Network.NetworkUser` object, In the end, don't forget to write the document back. That's it.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Hi Alex, it worked. Thanks man. I invested like 4 hrs behind this before posting it over here. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205435/discussion-between-ankit-ostwal-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful for someone else, as Alex said in the previous post, the problem is happening because Firestore doesnt know the Object "NetworkUser". So an approach to handle This is to convert the object in a Json String as follows:

1.- Before Insert, create a new Hashmap<String, String>

2.- Iterate over your old Hashmap<String, Object>, and using Gson (or another) do :

```
        val gson = Gson()
        for ((key, user) in my_old_hashmap) {
            val user  = gson.toJson(user)
            my_new_hashmap[key] = user
        }
```

3.- Proceed to insert in firestore as you insert any structure.

4.- Then for read this convert again to "your structure" using gson:

```
for ((key, user_string) in my_new_hashmap) {
      val user  = gson.fromJson(user_string, My_Object_Any::class.java)
       my_old_hashMap[key] = user
        }
```

TL;DR: Firestore doesn't Know your structure, so the HashMap to insert can be <String, String> or any other primitive Object supported by Firestore.