# What will happen if I use update method to update an array in the Firestore database?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to the documentation, we can not add or remove from an array in firestore, I have read a couple of methods like [Alex_Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629472/android-firebase-update-add-record-in-nested-array-data), [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611061/firestore-add-element-in-a-field-in-hashmap/59611639#59611639), also after reading a couple of answers I came to the conclusion instead of reading the entire array i save the array locally when i have to change something in that array and i update the locally saved array and use Update method to in firestore too

But I don't know if my approach of updating the entire array to change one field in Custom object.

My schema is like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFD76.png). Further, groups will have students array. so instead of removing the whole array I use the following code:

```
db.collection("teachers").document("user").update("myGroups", groups_arrayList).
addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
//done
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, we can. This [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will help you solve that. However, I'm not sure I understand the performance problem. What's the problem with the shared code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Alex, i have updated the question. I actually have read your blog which is written excellently.

Comment: So you're basically asking if it's ok to update an array of custom objects?

Comment: Yes because that array of the custom object may be changed in a way either name description or any element of the nested array has changed. Like deleting any element from the nested array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What are your worries?

Comment: Alex i have update the question, will you please take a look?

Comment: What is the result of using the shared code?